# How can I select a random element from an array based on the value of one of it's object properties?

Tags: java

If I have an array like this

```
resources[0] = new Resource("Brick", 0x990000, 3);
        resources[1] = new Resource("Wool", 0xFFFFFF, 4);
        resources[2] = new Resource("Lumber", 0x006600, 4);
        resources[3] = new Resource("Stone", 0x999999, 3);
        resources[4] = new Resource("Wheat", 0xFFFF33, 4);
        resources[5] = new Resource("Wasteland", 0xcc9966, 1);
```

How can I select a random resource that has an availability greater than 0?  Here is my current attempt:

```
int[] diceSpaces = {2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12};
diceSpaces = shuffleArray(diceSpaces);
 for(int i = 0; i < diceSpaces.length; i++){
                Resource currentResource = null;
                for(int r = 0; r < resources.length; r++){
                    int tryResource = new Random().nextInt(resources.length);
                    if(diceSpaces[i] != 7){
                        if(resources[tryResource].available > 0){
                            currentResource = resources[tryResource];
                            break;
                        }
                    } else {
                        currentResource = resources[5];
                        break;
                    }
                }
                currentResource.available--;
```

}

Comment: Your code is confusing... What's that i variable in there? Did you mean r.

Comment: This code is inside two more for loops that I did not include since I didn't think they were relevant.  Apologies.

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 what's not working?

Comment: It selects the same resource every time.

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 what is `i`? Is `diceSpaces[i]` always equal to `7`?

Comment: Is the resource-avaliability the third parameter in the constructor of the Resource class?

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 your code looks like it should work...

Comment: @dosw yes, that's correct.

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 how do you know it is selecting the same resource every time? I have a feeling you might think that it is but maybe it's not?...

Comment: This code is inside a more complicated for loop that draws a hexagonal-shaped grid of hexagon-shaped tiles.  The code always draws out the "Brick" resource.

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 there is something else going on outside of the code we see...I don't see any issue with the code u posted.

Answer (score 1):

One very easy solution:

1. Use Lists instead of Arrays, and then turn to [Collections.shuffle()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) - that method puts your elements into a random order!
2. Then iterate the array, and pick the **first** element that fulfills (all) your condition(s).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have to first filter your array to have an availability greater than 0 and only after this call `new Random().nextInt(filteredResources.length)` to generate random number.

Answer (score 0):

```
Resource availableResources[] = new Resource[resources.length];
int count = 0;
            for(int r = 0; r < resources.length; r++){

                    if(resources[r].available > 0){
                        availableResources[count++] = resources[tryResource];
                    }
            }
int RandomResource = (rand.nextInt(count));
```

`availableResources[randomResource]` is what you require.